# controls on form not showing

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am having the issue where I can't see any of my controls on my form. Before I could see the comboBox but after running the program it is now invisible in designer view. Also if I try to add anything, no event will be generated upon click. For eg. if I add a textbox I can't access the textchanged event or any other event. Am not sure what is happening but I have attached my below function which is the "Form1_Load" that contains my only code.

```
 {
        {
            try
            {

                string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Carimed_Inventory;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con2.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Carimed; ";

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    string cari_des = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("Item_Description"));
                    suggestComboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des);
                }
                con2.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            };

            // TrySomeThings(); // <-- comment this to see the standard behavior
            //suggestComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look in the designer code see if the control is part of panel or group box tool and that panel is the one on the top as in its hidden or overlapped by something else. If you are not having compile time error then atleast you can be sure your controls are not deleted from the form.

Comment: Look at the Designer.cs file. Are your controls listed there? A bug in VS is sometimes a form will lose it's controls. You may have to make a new form.

Comment: @glant yes everything is there for it. Idk it shows fine during execution but isn't visible while editing

Comment: @Zath.yes they are there

Comment: @Jevon I would say try creating a another new solution/project and see if this happens again.

Comment: okay i'll try that out @glant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the fault was on my part. I had a .cs file that I worked on which was overriding the default winforms comboBox which in turn affected its visibility and the other controls to be added. Surprisingly what fixed it  was just removing the code from the form1_load which was filling my comboBox with the values and placed it in a function on its own so this is the newly created function.

```
void fillCari()//fill dropdown with values
    {
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=CMDLAP126;Initial Catalog=Carimed_Inventory;User ID = sa; Password = 123456;";
            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con2.Open();
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Item_Description FROM dbo.Carimed"; //select Convert(nvarchar(50),Item_Description)+ ':' +Convert(nvarchar(50),Item#) as Combined from Carimed
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                string cari_des = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("Item_Description"));
                suggestComboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des);
                suggestComboBox1.Text.Trim();
            }
            //con2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }



    }
```